# Wrong Jquery FadeIn behavior on my web site when a div is moved to be viewed

Tags: jquery, css, firebug

I am modifying an existing web site (www.gjelavoie.com).
I am using the jquery fadein() and fadeout() to display my Contact form avoiding my visitors to access temporarily the main page.  I still have an undesired effect:

While the Contact form appears (fadein), the main page (fadeout) is moved **downward** 
  to a not understandable position.

The good news is, when the contact form disappears (fadeout), the main page (fadein),
is moved back to the correct previous position.

The bad news is, this is an undesirable behavior.
I used firebug to observe the style properties changes on the fly to figure out what does change in the page... (or differently said) I have tried observing the css attributes for possible positions movements (with firebug, chrome inspector and opera inspector), but no luck, I just don't get it.

Please can someone tell me how to debug this thing using a proper tool, or redirect me to the right function under the firebug family tools (firebug, chrome, ...), as the technique to resolve this issue might be useful for other future bug ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post some code for us. It's hard to get a crystal ball this days. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `lightbox-life.js`, you only need one $(document).ready(). No need to call it 5 times.

This is a CSS issue.

```
add / change these
#lightbox-panel {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    position: absolute;
}

remove this
#lightbox-panel {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Also, Firebug is one of the best debugging tools around.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer... I will test it and come back to this message.

Comment: Looks good at first, but then, I might of included another error in doing those changes... I wget the site on my host, made de changes and I do get the fadout of the main page but when I close the contact form, I get the following error from firefox: Erreur d'analyse XML : aucun élément trouvé
Emplacement : jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.jar!/chrome/toolkit/content/global/netError.xhtml
Numéro de ligne 1, Colonne 1 : ???

Comment: I understood the $(document).ready() comment.  Thanks for this one.  I am correcting it now.  But still don't understand the firefox error.

Comment: Ok, the error from firefox: "jar... netError.xhtml" is probably related to a missing html on the local disk.  The wget did not fetched it for an unknown reason, another issue.  I got the file and everything seems ok.  I will still test everything tomorrow.  Please, can you explain to me the bad CSS behavior... ? And finally, could I have found this error playing with firebug ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see this on the live site?

I'm not quite sure what you mean exactly, but I think you might need to use position:absolute on the contact form so it doesn't push the page down.

Comment: Yes the website in online, and I am a bit a shame of this behavior.

Comment: Sorry for this unclearness.  If you go to the www.gjelavoie.com/, in the English version, you see the "Courriel: info@gjelavoie.com".  Clicking this link will lead to the main page going down.

Comment: jhoffs code works correct. You need position:absolute to overlay it over the page, and the left and margin-left for positioning..

Comment: It seems the problem is resolve for now.  I still do not understand your (and jhoff) changes.  Why the browser did bring the main page down... What CSS attribute or rule the browser tried to respect ?